# Angular material, crear elementos dinamicamente con mat-autocomplete, se borra lo del input

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

Buen dia, tengo un problema con un elemento **mat-autocomplete** que lo creo dinamicamente con angular material, y este es el codigo de la vista:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="crearDotacion()">Crear Dotación</button>

<div *ngFor="let dot of crearMateriales; let i = index">

   <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
        <input matInput placeholder="Material" aria-label="Material" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="miControl" [(ngModel)]="dot.selectMaterial" >
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let material of materiales | async" (click)='changeMaterial2(material,i)' [value]="material.v_nombre_material">           
            <span>{{ material.v_nombre_material }}</span>                     
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field> 

 <div>
```

El codigo del .ts:

```
newServicio(){

    const property = {
        'selectMaterial': null,
        'tallas': null,
        'selectTalla': null,
        'cantidad': null,
        'stock': null,
        'stock_statico': null,
        'selectTipo': null,
        'selectObs': null,
        'longitudTallas': 0,
        '_status': true
    }; 
    if ( this.crearMateriales.length < 10){
        this.crearMateriales.push(property);
    }
}
crearDotacion(){


    this.newServicio();
}
```

Me lanza el siguiente error al crear un nuevo nodo:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: BOTINES CALERO 37    '. Current value: 'model: null'.

Al mismo tiempo se borra lo del input buscado.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primeramente el primer error que noto en tu codigo a simple vista es que no cierras la etiqueta **div**. Ahora bien si estas utilizando **ngModel** no es recomendable utilizar **formControl** y esto lo veraz en la consola ya que te lo advierte en un *warning*.

Si revisas https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel que es donde se explica ésto en la documentación te darás cuenta que ya está obsoleto:

> ## Usar con ngModel
>
> El soporte para usar la ngModelpropiedad de entrada y el ngModelChangeevento con directivas de forma reactiva ha quedado obsoleto en Angular v6 y se eliminará en Angular v7.

A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como quedaria tu código quitando el **formControl** mencionado anteriormente **(En éste caso dejo también el codigo del ts que utilice para realizar mis pruebas, aunque para resolver el problema que mencionas solo bastaria con quitar el formControl)**:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="crearDotacion()">Crear Dotación</button>

<div *ngFor="let dot of crearMateriales; let i = index">

   <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
        <input matInput placeholder="Material" aria-label="Material" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="dot.selectMaterial" >
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let material of materiales | async" (click)='changeMaterial2(material,i)' [value]="material.v_nombre_material">           
            <span>{{ material.v_nombre_material }}</span>                     
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field> 

 </div>
```

---

**TypeScript (.ts)**

Variables:

```
crearMateriales = [];
miControl = new FormControl();
arrMateriales = [{v_nombre_material: 'material 1'}, {v_nombre_material: 'material 2'}, {v_nombre_material: 'material 3'}]
materiales: Observable<Array<any>>;
```

Métodos:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.materiales = this.miControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.arrMateriales.slice())
    );
  }

  newServicio(){
    const property = {
      'selectMaterial': null,
      'tallas': null,
      'selectTalla': null,
      'cantidad': null,
      'stock': null,
      'stock_statico': null,
      'selectTipo': null,
      'selectObs': null,
      'longitudTallas': 0,
      '_status': true
    }; 
    if ( this.crearMateriales.length < 10){
      this.crearMateriales.push(property);
    }
  }
  crearDotacion(){
    this.newServicio();
  }
  changeMaterial2(material, i) {
    console.log('Haqui tu código cuando haces click');
  }
  private _filter(name: string) {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    return this.arrMateriales.filter(option => option.v_nombre_material.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

Prueba con esto y dime como te fue. Saludos ;)

Comment: Estimado Israel, gracias, si bien ya no sale el error anterior la busqueda del siguiente elemento creado se trunca, es decir se congela, gracias por tu colaboracion.

Comment: Tal vez si modificaras tu pregunta y añadieras la parte de como realizas tu `Observable` y tu cargado podria ayudarte más ya que esa parte yo la complete posiblemente allí exista algun error

Comment: this.materiales = this.miControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
         startWith(''),
         map(material=>material ? this._filtrarMateriales(material):this.materiales2)
         );   
y la funcion del filtrado es esta:

Comment: private _filtrarMateriales(value: string): Material[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();           
        return this.materiales2.filter(material => material.v_nombre_material.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    }

Comment: Seria mucho mejor que lo subieras a un repositorio como github o stackblitz para una revision con más detalle, si es que pudieras ;)

Comment: una consulta como puedo enviar a la vista el index, de let i=index, ese es mi problema pineso, es decir : #auto1="matAutocomplete",#auto2="matAutocomplete" y en la parte de arriba: [matAutocomplete]="auto1", [matAutocomplete]="auto2"...

Comment: Bueno modificaré mi respuesta y pondré el código que realicé para mis pruebas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102956/discussion-between-israel-icm-and-joselo).

Comment: Se pudo solucionar el problema gracias a este link, donde se muestra un ejemplo: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-material-autocomplete?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html] gracias israel por vuestra ayuda